Can 2 firebase-hosted Vue SPAs be connected client-side whereas the main app lives at example.com and the other at sub.example.com?
We have a Vue2 SPA hosted via firebase.
Now we split a part of that app to become a new app under a subdomain. This new app works with Nuxt (using SSR) and Vue3.*
For this we created a second server function with firebase.
Now, when landing on a page of the new app this page might include links to pages that are still part of the main app under example.com: i.e. on sub.example.com/lander we have a link that routes to "/faq", but the FAQ page is part of the old app and lives under example.com/faq.
Is there a way to connect both apps in the sense that no page reload is needed?
Or at least a way to make sure signed in users routing from app1 to app2 stay signed in?
*) The future goal is it to migrate the entire app to the Nuxt+Vue3 ecosystem, but that might take a while..

But "Is there a way to connect both apps in the sense that no page reload is needed?" the answer is no. /faq needs to be a regular link rather than router link. Could be made accessible on the same domain with a proxy, can't say if this will help with firebase auth
